# jeditable inline editing - value not showing after edit gets saved

Tags: jquery, jeditable, inline-editing

JEDITABLE LINK: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

My jquery function is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.edit').editable('http://myWebsite/save.php');
 });
```

I have a div which, when the page loads, looks like this:

```
<div class="edit" id="specs_1851_title" style="color:#C300D9">Starting Text</div>
```

Using jeditable, i'm able to click it, change it, and save the changes... this all works fine (I can see that the item got changed in the database and everything)

Now, after the value is saved, jeditable is supposed to take away the text input box, and display the newly entered text... instead, i get this:

```
<div class="edit" id="specs_1850_title" style="color:#C300D9">Click to Edit</div>
```

I opened the jquery.jeditable.js file and did a search for "Click to Edit".  The only place it appears is under the publicly accessible defaults:

```
$.fn.editable.defaults = {
    name       : 'value',
    id         : 'id',
    type       : 'text',
    width      : 'auto',
    height     : 'auto',
    event      : 'click.editable',
    onblur     : 'cancel',
    loadtype   : 'GET',
    loadtext   : 'Loading...',
    placeholder: 'Click to edit',
    loaddata   : {},
    submitdata : {},
    ajaxoptions: {}
};
```

has anybody ran into this problem before?  if so, what's the solution?

**UPDATE**
Immediately after posting the question, i thought "I wonder if my "save.php" can simply echo the value it updates in the database.  So, after running my mysql query to update the database, i put in:

```
echo $value;
```

And it worked just fine.  Kind of an odd work around - and i'm sure it's not the way it's supposed to work, but if anybody else runs into the same problem i'm having, there is a hack-solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the save.php script echo the result, this is no workaround.

I ran into the same question, and I agree that the explanation page isn't clear at this point.
However after diving into the Live Demo they offer (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html) and testing their save.php scripts I concluded that they also echo the submitted value. So this must be the requirement.

Your "Click to Edit" content is caused by the placeholder option which defines the text to display when no content is available, since your script returns no content it will load this placeholder value, which defaults to "Click to Edit" when you didn't specify it yourself.